# Video couldn't be cued in onActivityResult()

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-youtube-api, onactivityresult

I have two activities: `MainActivity` has a `youtubePlayerView` to display video from YouTube and a button "Chose", `ChoseVideoActivity` has 2 buttons with text "Video1" and "Video2".

At `MainActivity` I clicked the "Chose" button to open `ChoseVideoActivity`. In `ChoseVideoActivity`, I could click either of the two buttons.

When the button with text "video1" is clicked, the activity sends back the YouTube ID of video 1. When the button with text "video2" is clicked, the activity sends back the YouTube ID of video 2.

In `onActivityResult`, I call `cueVideo()` with the ID that is sent back.
It should have worked but it didn't.
It worked fine when i work in the same activity.

I used the YouTube Android player API.

**onActivityResult() in MainActivity**

```
 private void addEvents() {
    btChose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChoseVideoActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) 
    {
        String link = data.getStringExtra("LINK");
        player.cueVideo(link);
        Toast.makeText(this, link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    player = youTubePlayer;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Click listener in ChoseVideoActivity**

```
private void addEvents() {
    btVideo1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("LINK",link_video1);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
    btVideo2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("LINK",link_video2);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am new here so I can't comment on your post. Your code seems okay. As we can't see that how are you opening the next activity, so I want to make sure, Are you really using startActivityForResult function for opening second activity?
Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, that's how i start the second activity
But what's wrong with it?

Comment: Are you sure, Are you really coming in onActivityResult callback? if yes then you check are you really going to if condition and can debug the value of LINK, otherwise you can try to put URL string directly to the cueVideo function and see whether the video is working or not. if yes, then means your link value returns null or not correct value. please check that and let me know

Comment: i put the URL string directly to the cueVideo function, it's still the same, it doesn work :(

Comment: Then I need to check, how cueVideo function works, and make sure or you really coming in this callback? can you see the toast message you are printing in onActivityResult callback?

Comment: Can you please check is it coming to the onInitializationSuccess callback, it seems player context is null, that's why it is not playing video.